# Get value from another column in the same row when "if" passes in Pandas Python CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, csv

I'm trying to integrate code from different files in csv.

I searches for documentation, but can't really understand the Pandas library to get my code working.

The CSV table:

```
ID     | Quantity
-------+---------
235235 | 5
125772 | 4
647454 | 2
236344 | 8
```

I have a list full of ID's. I want to match the ID's from CSV with the ID's from another list, and get the exact value of `Quantity` column of same row.

For example:

236344 = 8

If I'm getting the 236344 id from id_list, then the function is checking if is it the match in the csv file, and gives the correct value of `Quantity`

125772  = 4

(Simplified):

```
id_list = open('')
csv_list = pandas.read_csv('', header=0 )

for id_1 in id_list:
  for id_2 in csv_list:
    if( id_1 == id_2 ):
       quantity_value = (value_from_csv)
```

I need to pass the quantity_value after it to another function.

I tried to use the `df.loc[]`, but can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: where is `id_list` ?

Comment: id_list and csv_list path is in my programm correct. I meant with this simplified code to show , what i'm wiling to archieve, and what the output shoud be.

Comment: I mean where is it in the [mcve] above - what list are you checking against?

Comment: One list(id_list) is in the web(php/html), which contains only the id's. the program downloads the list using the urlib, and get's rid of some extras, so it only the ids line by line is sorted. The another list is also in the Web and it is a csv file. Both file need to be Online. The program is meant for syncronisation and data processing. So basicly i'm trying to check the ID from one list agains another, and get the value from csv for this specific id.